# VOIP call problems on samsung s4 running 4.4.2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, voip

I recently updated my Samsung Galaxy S4 to 4.4.2 and since then my VOIP calls are not going.
Video calls work but audio calls don't. I have tried whilst connected to 2g/3g/WiFi and I have also tried removing "OK Google" but this has not helped.
Also I tried Factory reset.
It worked for first 3 -4 calls and now still facing same problems

Comment: What VOIP software are you using?

Comment: I tried talkray, skype and we chat

Comment: What actually happens when you try to make the call?

Comment: call is not connecting